# Laravel Incorrect date value sql_mode empty

Tags: mysql, sql, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

I have a problem executing a sql update/insert using Laravel's Query Builder (`DB` Facade).  When inserting a row into a table I get the

> QueryException: Invalid datetime format: 1292 Incorrect date value:
>   '0000-00-00' for column 'FoundationDate'.

When I copy the SQL statement to PHPMyAdmin, it works without problems. I know it depends on the `sql_mode` setting. I checked this variable and there is no strict mode enabled! So how is this possible that it works on PHPMyAdmin but in Laravel it doesn't?

I'm using Mysql 5.5.49 and Laravel 5.3.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Where did you check the variable? The value can be set for current session and a decent framework should always do it. Whatever, I think it'd be less messy to just prevent invalid dates to happen in the first place.

Comment: In PhpMyAdmin you can check variable values (Tab "Variables"). The variable sql_mode is empty.

Comment: PhpMyAdmin is not part of your Laravel application so it'll be establishing its own database connections. You need to verify the value from PHP itself.

Comment: I'll clarify: go to "Search/ Find in files" and look for the string "sql_mode" in your entire codebase.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Laravel 5.3 sql_mode is set at runtime by `Illuminate\DatabaseConnectors\MySqlConnector@setModes`:

```
/**
 * Set the modes for the connection.
 *
 * @param  \PDO  $connection
 * @param  array  $config
 * @return void
 */
protected function setModes(PDO $connection, array $config)
{
    if (isset($config['modes'])) {
        $modes = implode(',', $config['modes']);

        $connection->prepare("set session sql_mode='{$modes}'")->execute();
    } elseif (isset($config['strict'])) {
        if ($config['strict']) {
            $connection->prepare("set session sql_mode='ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY,STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION'")->execute();
        } else {
            $connection->prepare("set session sql_mode='NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION'")->execute();
        }
    }
}
```

Notice sql_mode's `NO_ZERO_DATE` is set in that method. The sql_mode can be altered in your config.database.php file by adding a `modes` key to your mysql connection like below:

```
'connections' => [
    'mysql' => [
        'driver' => 'mysql',
        'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
        'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
        'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
        'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
        'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
        'charset' => 'utf8',
        'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
        'prefix' => '',
        'strict' => true,
        'engine' => null,
        'modes'  => [],
    ],
]
```

You can leave `modes` as an empty array or configure it how you want. More info [here](https://github.com/laravel/framework/pull/12030)

Alternatively, you can just set `strict => false,`

Comment: `strict => false,` is the way. Thank you, sir.

Answer (score 0):

Laravel DB insert, unlike eloquent does not create dates for you. Since you have `FoundationDate` in your table is of type Datetime, you have to manually set it.

```
DB::table("users")->insert([
    ...
    'FoundationDate' => \Carbon\Carbon::now()
]);
```

Comment: I have the value '0000-00-00' which comes from another source and should be '0000-00-00' in the database later.

Comment: Well, '0000-00-00' is not a correct Datetime string. So laravel wont insert it by default; You can add to your model `protected $timestamps = false;`

Comment: The column type is `date`. For this type it's a correct date-value as long as strict mode is disabled. PHPMyAdmin accepts it, only Laravel throws an exception (which actually comes from mysql).

Comment: Did you make the attribute `nullable()` in the migrations ?

Comment: You said is of type `date`. Your error says otherwise. `QueryException: Invalid "datetime" format`. My guess is that something in the migration.

Comment: @Yannici How does `0000-00-00` behave differently than `NULL` in your application?

Comment: @EddyTheDove But after that it says "Incorrect date value". No its not nullable, but I tried it with nullable but want to set 0000-00-00.

Comment: @Álvaro González Its the same. But I want to allow 0000-00-00 anyway because I get it from an API request.

Comment: @Yannici try to set your database to `InnoDB` if not yet.

Comment: @Yannici So you want to intentionally not validate or process incoming dates? What if the API returns `2017-02-29` or `unknown`?

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález Good point but actually I'm calling the api from another page by myself and only by myself. The source is another database (which has 0000-00-00 dates). Its like a transfer from one database to antoher database by api request.